# How to write a shell script to clone all of my repo's from gitlab

Tags: git, shell

Question is I would like to write a simple shell script to clone my repo's from my internal gitlab. The main thing I am kind of confused about is how to loop through and clone each project, and also how to check if the project exist or not. This is what I have so far any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

gitlab_pull_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash


BLUE='\033[0;34m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
NC='\033[0m' 

printf "${GREEN}Initializing starting sciprt${BLUE} Pulling from code.mydomain.com${NC}\n"

#var's
codeHost=mydomain.com
codeUser=admin
testApp1="git@$codeHost:$codeUser/testapp1.git"
testApp2="git@$codeHost:$codeUser/testapp2.git"
testApp3="git@$codeHost:$codeUser/testapp3.git"
testApp4="git@$codeHost:$codeUser/testapp4.git"
testApp5="git@$codeHost:$codeUser/testapp5.git"

#this is the part I'm not sure about for checking to make sure the project exist 
codeProjects="$tesApp1" && "$tesApp2" && "$tesApp3" && "$tesApp4" && "$tesApp5"


localCodeDir="${HOME}/code/"


do 
   #once again im not sure if this works to check $codeprojects variable  if it exist or not. 
   if [ -z "$codeProjects" ]; then
      echo "Project not found"
      exit
   else # this is where I am confused on how to make loop through each project ********
      cloneCmd="git clone $testApp1"
      cloneCmd="git clone $testApp2"
      cloneCmd="git clone $testApp3"
      cloneCmd="git clone $testApp4"
      cloneCmd="git clone $testApp5"
   fi
done
```

Comment: http://ss64.com/bash/for.html

Comment: There is difference between Git Pull and Git Clone. Which one you are trying to do?

Comment: Git clone, I was thinking of having a separate script do the pull and have it as cron job. @user2984552

Comment: Obtaining a list of your projects would be slightly more challenging but I imagine gitlab provides an API for enumerating your projects.  But if you are content with hard-coding a list of projects into the script, this is not hard at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for app in testapp1 testapp2 testapp3 foo bar emacs-snapshot; do
    git clone "git@$codeHost:$codeUser/$app.git"
done
```

If you absolutely want the projects in a variable, assigning them to an array (or even simply a space-delimited quoted string) works fine.

```
apps=(testapp1 testapp2 testapp3 foo bar emacs-snapshot)
for app in "${apps[@]}"; do
    :
```

or even

```
apps="testapp1 testapp2 testapp3 foo bar emacs-snapshot"
for app in $apps; do
    :
```

I wouldn't worry about checking for a project's existence -- `git` will throw an error and skip that project, and the loop continues with the next one in the list.

Comment: The third suggestion worked the best, the script run's but each time it clones a project it is requiring my pub.key how can I had that in so this can be an automated script? because when I put in my pass phrase it says I do not have access to this repo which doesnt make sense cause if I do git clone myrepo manually it works. any idea's? @tripleee

Comment: That's really a separate question, and a massive FAQ.  Google for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This tool does exactly what you need with minimal setup: https://github.com/akhikhl/multiproject-git-gradle

Requires installation of Java and Gradle.